# How can I trigger Mollom to detect a form submission as spam?

Tags: drupal, forms, spam-prevention, spam

I am testing a form using the [Mollom Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/mollom). I have tried submitting some posts that I thought would trip the spam filter (using the word "viagara" repeatedly), but it didn't catch them. How can I trigger the spam filter for testing purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mollom has a developer mode. Check out the [How do I test Mollom?](http://mollom.com/faq/how-do-i-test-mollom) page and the [Testing Mollom without damaging your reputation](http://drupal.org/node/350424) page.